# php substring occurances between two strings in an html file

Tags: php, substring

So i have an HTML file as source, it contains several instances of the following code:

```
<span itemprop="name">NAME</span>
```

where the NAME part always changing to something different.

how can i write a php code that would go through the html code, extract all the names between the "`<span itemprop="name">`" and "`</span>`" and put it in an array?

i have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
$prev=$html;

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
     $current = explode('<span itemprop="name">', $prev);
     $cur = explode('</span>', $current[1]);
     $names[] =  $cur[0];

     $prev = $current[2];
}

print_r($names);
```

Comment: By learning php. And mostly string functions for this case http://php.net/strings

Comment: I have tried several things, like this: `code`$prev=$html;

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
  $current = explode('<span itemprop="name">', $prev);
  $cur = explode('</span>', $current[1]);
  $names[] =  $cur[0];
  
  $prev = $current[$i+2];
}

print_r($names); but it doesnt work

Comment: @YehiaNada What have you tried? You might include that in your question.

Comment: @YehiaNada post the code you used in your question, not in a comment. You can edit it to add those lines

Comment: I just did, it only prints the first occurrence.

Comment: why `$current[2]` ? (the `2` part .. )

Comment: i thought i would advance the search into the second exploded part of the string, i guess my concept is wrong. AliTrixx code works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably better way would be using php [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [simple php dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or any DOM representative than the way you planed.

Here is example of working DOMDocument code:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('<html><body><span itemprop="name">1</span><span itemprop="name">2</span><span itemprop="name">3</span></body></html>');
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);

    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@itemprop, 'name')]");

    foreach($nodes as $node)
    {   
        echo $node->nodeValue . '<br />';
    }
```

**Outputs:**

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: awesome, what i'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

This function will get us the "NAME"

```
function getbetween($content,$start,$end) {
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
```

This function will replace only the first occurence

```
<?php
function str_replace_once($search, $replace, $subject) {
    $firstChar = strpos($subject, $search);
    if($firstChar !== false) {
        $beforeStr = substr($subject,0,$firstChar);
        $afterStr = substr($subject, $firstChar + strlen($search));
        return $beforeStr.$replace.$afterStr;
    } else {
        return $subject;
    }
}
?>
```

now a loop

```
$start = '<span itemprop="name">';
$end = '</span>';
while(strpos($content, $start)) {
    $name = getbetween($content, $start, $end);
    $content = str_replace_once($start.$name.$end, '',$content);
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: thank you, i have a question though, this deletes the element after it looks for it, but what if there are similar occurences of the string? I want it to also be printed/counted for in the array.

Comment: In that case we'd have to use another function to replace only the first occurrence. I will edit my question now to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda feel bad for saying this... but you could use a regular expression

```
preg_match_all('/<span itemprop="name">(.*?)<\/span>/i', $matches);
var_dump($matches); // results are stored in the variable $matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'this is my [tag]dog[/tag]';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '[tag]', '[/tag]');

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

Ref[enter link description here](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/)